# karate framework - how to count number of arrays in json response

Tags: arrays, json, counting, karate

there

I have a JSON response as below:

```
"log": [{
        "a": 0.40,
        "b": "ED",
    }, {
        "c": 82,
        "d": "ABC",
    }, {
        "e": 36,
        "f": 23,
    }, {
        "g": 12,
        "h": 40,
    }
]
```

I need to count a number of lists in a 'log' object to be able to address the last one and find a specific element in it. The response is dynamic and has different amount of lists in it (in this case 4)

I tried log[-1], and examples form js-arrays.feature as in the link below:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature#L83

It is easy to find a number of elements in a list, but I frequently have variable amount of lists and I cant make it work
Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take into account that log[-1] would return you undefined due to there is no index `-1` in the array. For get the number of elements in your array you must do

```
log.length
```

Also about the link you've posted

```
log[log.length-1]; //This will return the last element of the array in this case { "g": 12, "h": 40, }
```

Comment: Hi Brank. Thanks for your help. This actually has made the trick. I have now the last list of this array of lists and I can access it. I did not think I could be done this way. Many Thanks